# Can a Fully Connected layer transform a 4D tensor to a 3D tensor by itself?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, tensor

Recently, I was researching some topics in biometrics and I stumbled upon [this paper](https://www.isca-speech.org/archive/Interspeech_2017/pdfs/0360.PDF). They have a table there (Table 1) in which they state that they used a modified CNN from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02683.pdf) (Table 9). In the latter, the first FC layer outputs a 2D tensor as expected (batch x 512), in the former however they claim that it outputs a 3D tensor (batch x 32 x 2). Is this possible? Isn't it a mistake? I always thought that one has to flatten the tensor before FC layer so I'm confused how is it possible to suddenly go from 4D to 3D tensor using just FC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, Fully Connected (FC) layers have no concept of dimensionality.

However, if I wanted to use a FC layer passing into another layer which had specific dimensionality requirements, I would simply use FC to create the correct number of samples (e.g. 32x2=64 samples) and then reshape the output into the correct dimensionality.

A quick Keras example:

```
... # some layers, probably a Flatten() included
fc_out = keras.layers.Dense(64)(previous_layer)
fc_out_reshaped = keras.layers.Reshape([32, 2])(fc_out)
... # now you can do 1D conv, or RNN, or whatever you want
```